# Is there any way I can simplify the colours in a region of an image using OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, k-means

I am trying to use kmeans clustering to reduce the number of colours in an image and simplify it to some distinct regions of the same colour. An example of a good result that I have gotten using just kmeans can be seen in these images of a portion of sky in an image.

[Input sky](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N89FY.png)

[Output sky](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcZFj.png)

However, other regions in images have resulted in grainy less distinct regions. An example can be seen in the two images below.

[Input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2rJc.png)

[Grainy output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ctfgl.png)

Are there any methods that I can use to make the borders between the colours more distinct or any methods that can take a small matrix of pixels and allocate the most frequent colour in the matrix to all of the pixels in that matrix?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You do not show your kmeans code?  How many levels in K?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).